# How widely used are "classic" high-Tc superconductors?

Tags: electrical-engineering, cryogenics, superconduction

Are there good examples of the "high temperature" superconductors developed since the late 80s being used commercially? These only work at temperatures that are high relative to liquid helium, generally operating in the liquid nitrogen range. Even though that is still cryogenic, at one time it was thought that superconductors even in that temperature range could be transformative. My impression is that they have not. Am I wrong?

As evidence, consider [this announcement](https://www.medimaging.net/mri/articles/294795607/use-of-high-temperature-superconductors-to-make-mr-imaging-more-affordable-accessible-and-sustainable.html) of a research project, starting in 2022, to use these superconductors in an MRI machine. That does not sound like rapid market penetration, 35 years after their first invention. But is there a niche I'm not aware of?

I think this question is timely because of all the excitement about claims of a standard-temperature-and-pressure superconductor. Obviously, that's a much better temperature regime than the old "high-Tc" superconductors. But I am wondering if there still might be drawbacks (lack of ductility? limited capacity?) that would limit their transformative impact. It seems like a hard look at the yttrium-barium superconductors and their descendants might be informative.